# Font Awesome - Stacking and other things just doesn't work

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I'm using Font Awesome to make something like "social bar". Here's the problem, I can do the circle (as seen on picture) easily in CSS, but the circle is regular (even) so I want to do it by the Font Awesome way (http://fontawesome.io/examples/#stacked), but it seems it doesn't work for me.
The way I did it in CSS:

[image: The way I did it in CSS]

And in HTML file it looked like this:

```
<div class="social-box">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#steam"><i class="fa fa-steam"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And CSS (I'm using Sass):

```
.social-box {
    background: $main-color;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: $sidebar-width;
    height: $sidebar-socialbox-size;
    ul {
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        padding-top: ($sidebar-socialbox-size - $sidebar-socialbox-height)/2;
        left: 50%;
        li {
            width: $sidebar-socialbox-height;
            height: $sidebar-socialbox-height;
            margin: 0 $sidebar-socialbox-padding;
            float: left;
            right: 50%;
            position: relative;
            a {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                display: block;
                text-decoration: none;
                i {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    display: block;
                    background: $main-color-2;
                    color: $main-color;
                    text-align: center;
                    font-size: $sidebar-socialbox-icon-size;
                    line-height: $sidebar-socialbox-height;
                }
                &:hover {
                    i {
                        background: $sidebar-socialbox-background-hover;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I added this to my HTML file and now it looks like this:

```
<div class="social-box">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                    <a href="#facebook"></a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                    <a href="#twitter"></a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-steam fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                    <a href="#steam"></a>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

And edited CSS file a little bit:

```
.social-box {
    background: $main-color;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: $sidebar-width;
    height: $sidebar-socialbox-size;
    ul {
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        padding-top: ($sidebar-socialbox-size - $sidebar-socialbox-height)/2;
        left: 50%;
        li {
            width: $sidebar-socialbox-height;
            height: $sidebar-socialbox-height;
            margin: 0 $sidebar-socialbox-padding;
            float: left;
            right: 50%;
            position: relative;
            span {
                a {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    display: block;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }
                i {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    display: block;
                    background: $main-color-2;
                    color: $main-color;
                    text-align: center;
                    font-size: $sidebar-socialbox-icon-size;
                    line-height: $sidebar-socialbox-height;
                }
                &:hover {
                    i {
                        background: $sidebar-socialbox-background-hover;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now it looks like this:
[image: Now it looks like this]

Ideas why this happens?

Comment: create a working example/demo so people can investigate

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask]. There is no way to know what the value of all those SASS variables are supposed to be, post your compiled CSS.